# Separate trigger for Material-UI Drawer Component

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

If I have a material-ui `Drawer` component, how can I toggle that state using an element separate from the drawer itself?  In all the examples they use something like this:

```
export class DrawerSimpleExample extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {open: false};
    }

    handleToggle = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open});

    render() {
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={customTheme}>

            <div>
                <RaisedButton
                    label="Toggle Drawer"
                    onClick={this.handleToggle}
                />
                <Drawer open={this.state.open}
                        docked={true}
                >
                    <MenuItem>Menu Item</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
                </Drawer>
            </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}
```

But what if I want to have that `RaisedButton` be inside an `AppBar` instead?  Like so:

```
export class AppBarExampleIconButton extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={customTheme}>

            <AppBar
                    title={<span style={styles.title}>Title</span>}
                    onTitleClick={handleClick}
                    iconElementLeft={<div>
                        <IconButton><NavigationMenu /></IconButton>
                        // Have this button toggle the drawer instead
                        <RaisedButton
                            label="Toggle Drawer"
                            onClick={this.handleToggle}
                        />
                    </div>}
                    iconElementRight={<FlatButton label="Save" />}
                />
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}
```

And furthermore, what if I wanted to have the `Drawer` be permanently open, yet still toggleable from the `AppBar` (to where I would adjust the positioning/width of them on open/close).

Answer (score 0):

Toggle drawer with props instead of state.

```
export class AppBarExampleIconButton extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    openDrawer: false,
    }
}
handleToggle=()=>{this.setState({openDrawer: !this.state.openDrawer});

render() {
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={customTheme}>

        <AppBar
                title={<span style={styles.title}>Title</span>}
                onTitleClick={handleClick}
                iconElementLeft={<div>
                    <IconButton><NavigationMenu /></IconButton>
                    // Have this button toggle the drawer instead
                    <RaisedButton
                        label="Toggle Drawer"
                        onClick={this.handleToggle}
                    />
                </div>}
                iconElementRight={<FlatButton label="Save" />}
            />
          <DrawerSimpleExample open = {this.state.openDrawer}/>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

In your DrawerSimple component:

```
export class DrawerSimpleExample extends React.Component { 
    render() {
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={customTheme}>
            <div>
                <Drawer open={this.props.open}
                        docked={true}>
                    <MenuItem>Menu Item</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
                </Drawer>
            </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}
```